# Adding items to perl cgi th

Tags: perl, cgi

Is there a way to add additional params (namely classes) to a th call when using the perl cgi module?

I know we can use a bunch of prints/etc but I want to see if we can use the th

Here's my th call:

```
print th({-class=>'myClass'},['Col1','Col2',@MoreColumns]);
```

It sets the myClass for ALL the columns.  I want to set for just one column and/or set diff ones for each column

I would like it to be something like:

```
<thead>
 <tr>
    <th class=specialClass>Col1
    <th class=AnotherClass>Col2
    <th class=ArrayClass>Col3FromArray
    <th class=ArrayClass>Col4FromArray
    <th class=ArrayClass>Col4FromArray
 </tr>
</thead>
```

Is this possible with perl cgi th([ or do I need to use a bunch of prints/loop?

Comment: `<td>` tags inside `<th>` tags? My head is exploding.

Comment: sorry i fixed my post ... I was using wrong tags ... should be thead and th

Comment: Please stop using the dirty old CGI.pm. Use instead a modern and clean web engine such as [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/) or [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Your expected HTML or XHTML is invalid. `<th>` can only be used in places where `<td>` is legal; it is not a special `<tr>`. If you're expecting XHTML (as opposed to HTML), there are two further problems: all tags must be closed and all attribute values must be quoted.
2. AFAIK the [`CGI.pm`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI) HTML construction methods can operate on single strings as well. Does the following work?

   ```
   print th({-class=>'specialClass'}, 'Col1'),
         th({-class=>'AnotherClass'}, 'Col2'),
         th({-class=>'ArrayClass'},   \@MoreColumns);
   ```